# How to make a startup entry in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, startup

I want to put a startup entry of my program in system so that it run everytime I start the system. But how to do in cocoa, i have no idea,Please provide me help for this.I m new bie in cocoa.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use something like this library from github: https://github.com/Mozketo/LaunchAtLoginController

```
LaunchAtLoginController *launchController = [[LaunchAtLoginController alloc] init];
[launchController setLaunchAtLogin:YES];
[launchController release];
```

Comment: I have created both classes but during compile time. I am getting error in LauchATLoginController.m error that (Loginitem is undeclare first use in the functions like) for this what i have to do.Please provide me help for that

Comment: Well, you probably forgot the header file. But it sounds like your problem is that you don't know Objective-C, maybe you should take some time to learn the language better? This question links to many good sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571/cocoa-and-objective-c-resources

Comment: Ya thats right, I am new to objective c.But i have to develop this app as soon as possible please help me and again thanks for your help

Comment: Try to add #import "LaunchAtLoginController.h" at the start of your .m file.

Comment: I have added "LaunchAtLoginController.h" in start of my "LaunchAtLoginController.m". But still getting same error and second thing i want to tell,I m not using any user interface for this.

Comment: This is a great answer. Why not accept it, and post a new question with the problem you're having using that library with your code pasted in?

Comment: @noa no doubt this is great answer. I have created both classes same as given in the code.I had import "LanunchAtLoginController.h" in my .m file then still I am getting these errors.I am using MAC 10.5.6. errors are as:                                                               1.'Loginitems' undeclare(first use in this function.                                                            2. sysntesized property 'Loginitems must be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar.