# How to get Modify shift key in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, get, key, shift

How to get the modify <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in cocoa. I am making an application and getting the values of all keys using Key code but not able to get the value of (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+modify key). Can anybody tell me how i can get this. I have no idea about this. Please provide me help. I am new bie in cocoa.

for all key code in MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documention at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/modifierFlags). There's a `- (NSUInteger)modifierFlags` method that returns the modifiers for the event. An you'll find the modifier flags [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/modifierFlags).

Edit some sample code to get the key :

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSString * character = [event characters];
    unichar keyCode = [character characterAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@" - Keydown -\n    >>%@<< ->> %c %i<<",character,keyCode, keyCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much sir. I have used flagchanged event to get the shift key.But I only getting the shift key.How i can get the key pressed with shift.

Comment: You can call either `- (NSString *)characters` or  `- (NSString *)charactersIgnoringModifiers`. They return characters but also [Function-Key unicode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/modifierFlags).

Comment: I wants to know how to get the keys that are pressed with shift,also want to know is there are any keycode for the keys(that are pressed with shift).I have used flagChanged events,But is giving me only (shiftkey,ctrlkey,Alt key).  sir Please provide me any example to get the key pressed with shift.because I am new bie to Cocoa.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I have searched many post,But did not find the good solution this post helped me very much and solved my problem.

Comment: How I can checked my question.I have no idea about this.

Comment: Left of my answer, there's a check mark that goes green when clicked !

Comment: Ok I will going to do it now.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426595/how-to-make-a-startup-entry-in-cocoa/11426999#11426999.There is a question on this link.Please provide me help in this.If you can.